# Android Pagination 3.0 not able to search after first try using kotlin flows

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

So, I have a pager setup using kotlin flows in android. I have a string that I get from the user and whenever that changes I use the flatmaplatest operator to get the latest item from the Pager object. The pager object is as follows.

```
 fun searchAedItem(search: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mutableSearchData.emit(search)
        }
    }


val searchFlow = mutableSearchData.flatMapLatest {

        IOLog.d(TAG, "search Flow happening..$it")
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("keyword", it)
        val gson = getGsonObject(jsonObject)

        Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 1)) { AedSearchSource(aedApi, gson) }.flow
    }
```

the above is inside my viewmodel and I'm observing these inside my activity as follows:

```
 lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewmodel.searchFlow.collect {
                IOLog.d("mutableSearchData", it.toString())
                adapter?.submitData(it)
            }
        }
```

My adapter seems to be running fine since there was no problem when I displayed it with a different list

AedSearchSource class looks like this.

```
class AedSearchSource(val aedApi: AedApi, val searchObje: JsonObject) :
    PagingSource<Int, AedDevicesListItem>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, AedDevicesListItem>): Int? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, AedDevicesListItem> {
        return try {
            val nextPage = params.key ?: 1
            val response = aedApi.serachAed(searchObje, nextPage).await()
            val list = response.body()!!

            return if (list.isEmpty()) {
                LoadResult.Error(Throwable("End of list reached."))
            } else
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = list,
                    prevKey = if (nextPage == 1) null else nextPage - 1,
                    nextKey = nextPage.inc()
                )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }

    }
}
```

so, the problem is that it only works the first time api gets called and executes fine. and then subsequent times when I have a different text in searchAedItem()  **Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 1)) { AedSearchSource(aedApi, gson) }.flow**  does not get executed. but the flatMapLatest executes just fine.but pager object doesnot execute that api that I want to search.
Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `.collectLatest` from your `Flow<PagingData>` in order to cancel the previous generation once it gets superseded by a new search term.